# SQL Query to display records not in the condition

Tags: mysql, database

I am having trouble on how to display records who are **not equal on b.sponsor_id=s.sponsor_id**. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question sounds like you want to join the tables whose aliases are `b` and `s` on some condition, and retain records which do *not* match.  If you wanted to retain records from `b` which do not match, then you can try using a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM tableB b
LEFT JOIN tableS s
    ON b.sponsor_id = s.sponsor_id
WHERE s.sponsor_id IS NULL
```